# Accessing parent window variable with Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync?

Tags: office-js

I'm opening and closing a Dialog Async with **Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync()**, 
When the page in the dialog pops up, I want to access a variable or DOM element defined in the parent window, that I would normally do using:

window.opener.**VariableName**
or
window.opener.$("#**ElementName**")

Is there a similar method for displayDialogAsync()?

PS: This variable string length is **too long** to be passed through GET variables in URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to do that. You would need to save the variable value in Local Storage with script on the parent page and read it from script in the dialog. You could use the messageParent function in the dialog to tell the parent when to save the variable.